# Why will an image display with absolute URL but not when I link to my local machine?

Tags: html, url, local

I'm working with HTML that was already built; all the pictures will work with my local machine except for the images in the slideshow.

This is the code that works:

```
   <div class="backgroundImage" id="homePageBanner2" style="background:url(http://demandware.edgesuite.net/aajh_prd/on/demandware.static/Sites-beats-Site/Sites-beats-Library/default/v1355443668325/images/homepage/2-seasonal-pill-gap_2400x650.jpg) center 0 no-repeat;">
                <img src="http://demandware.edgesuite.net/aajh_prd/on/demandware.static/Sites-beats-Site/Sites-beats-Library/default/v1355443668325/images/homepage/2-seasonal-pill-gap_2400x650.jpg" style="display:none;" />
            </div>
```

This won't, it just shows up black. (Keep in mind this format works for all the other pictures in this html.)

```
<div class="backgroundImage" id="homePageBanner1" style="background:"../demandware.edgesuite.net/aajh_prd/on/demandware.static/Sites-beats-Site/-/default/v1355443668325/images/MainImage2.png") center 0 no-repeat;">
            <img src="../demandware.edgesuite.net/aajh_prd/on/demandware.static/Sites-beats-Site/-/default/v1355443668325/images/MainImage2.png" style="display:none;" />
        </div>
```

Comment: `../demandware.edgesuite.net`. You seem to be using a relative URL, along with the hostname. Not sure why you would want to do that.

Comment: I guess it's just a format issue. Try using a `.jpg` image.

Comment: There's a typo: the opening `(` is missing or remove the closing `)`

Comment: @Ctlhulhu the demandware.edgesuit.net is the name of my folder, its the way it named the folder when i downloaded it from there servers

Comment: @mhu Sorry about that i alrady tried that i accidentally put the closing back

Comment: @RobertLamb You could edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: Can you please edit your question with your "good" code so that we can be sure that there are no "structural" mistakes?

Answer (score 3):

```
"background:"
```

Could be that you end your style right after you specify background:

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 image references here, one in the markup and one in the CSS style. Not sure, what the point is of that. 
If the style argument is really broken in the code, which is what appears to be the case from what you pasted, it is possible that the image sits in the document root and the CSS sits in a subfolder, so that only the relative URL for the background image works if the HTML file is also in the root. The image tag source URL would point to one folder above the root in the hierarchy and that's probably not where the image is. Because the background image CSS is broken in the local version, neither image appears.

Answer (score 0):

```
style="background:"../demandware.edgesuite.net/aajh_prd/on/demandware.static/Sites-beats-Site/-/default/v1355443668325/images/MainImage2.png") center 0 no-repeat;"
```

Did you mean:

```
style="background:url(../demandware.edgesuite.net/aajh_prd/on/demandware.static/Sites-beats-Site/-/default/v1355443668325/images/MainImage2.png) center 0 no-repeat;"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in business manager

> src="/images/homepage/2-seasonal-pill-gap_2400x650.jpg?$staticlink$"

if this is in an isml file

> src="${URLUtils.staticURL('/images/homepage/2-seasonal-pill-gap_2400x650.jpg')}"

Is the most consistent for all instances (dev, stg, development, and prod)